# Python Bokeh plotting tool - Changing the font size of the ticker(both X and Y axis)

Tags: python, bokeh

The problem which traps me is that I want to enlarge the font size in the ticker on both x and y-axis.

I am using the Bokeh as the tool for plotting. I can generate a neat plot now. But the ticker is way too small. As I went through google, I hardly find the solution. Huge thank. (Enlarge the font size within the red box)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`major_label_text_font_size`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html#bokeh.models.axes.Axis.major_label_text_font_size) attribute:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.circle(0, 0)
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "20px"

show(p)
```